# Vector Template C2228 left of '.size' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, templates, linker

```
template <class T>
void SaveLoadControl::SaveTreeToVector(std::vector<T>* Vector, boost::property_tree::ptree& Tree, std::string Type)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Vector.size(); i++)
    {
```

having an issue with the code, it says that the left side of '.size must have a class/struct/union. The Vector is populated with a template and i am unfamiliar with templates so far so am quite lost with this issue. Any help would be appreciated i already looked around and couldn't figure out why really. So would like to know.

Comment: Can you post a [MCVE] as usually required please?

Comment: `Vector` is a _pointer_ (to `vector<T>`). Try `(*Vector).size()` or `Vector->size()`.

Comment: Pass `Vector` by reference (why is it a pointer?)

Comment: ``Vector->size()`` should work as Vector is a pointer to a vector.